# Convergence of an integral with delta sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I am confused about the following problem:

Given that $(p^n)_n$ is a sequence of densities in $L^2$ which converges weakly to $p^0$, and

$\delta_n(x, x') := \sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}\exp\left( - \frac{n (x-x')^2}{2} \right)$.

The question is, whether $\int \delta_n(x,x')p^n(x')dx'$ converges to $p^0$ in some sense?

I know $\delta_n$ converges to the dirac delta function $\delta$ in the sense of distribtutions, and the above statement seems right, but I don't know how to prove it. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you say "densities", do you mean probability densities, i.e, nonnegative functions with integral equal to $1$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Are there some conditions on $p^n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some thoughts about the question which would be too long for a comment.

Denote $h_n(x):=\int \delta(x,x')p^n(x')dx=g_n\star p^n$ with $g_n(x)=\sqrt n(2\pi)^{-1/2}\exp(-x^2/2)$.

Firstly, using [Young's inequality for convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality#Young.27s_inequality_for_convolutions) with $r=q=2$ and $p=1$, and boundedness in $\mathbb L^2$ of $(p^n)_n$ we obtain that the sequence $(h_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is bounded in $\mathbb L^2$, hence it admits a weakly convergent subsequence.

Second, the result is true if $\lVert p^n-p\rVert_2\to 0$ using again Young's inequality and Fourier transform.

Comment: Thank you so much, these thoughts are really helpful, especially the application of Young's inequality.

Comment: You are welcome.